# Deleting lastChild of a cloned branch

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a div with 5 randomly spread images and another one to where I cloned/attached the whole branch of 5 images. Now I have to remove the last of the cloned children. That doesn’t work. The whole branch is removed instead. So, I tried to identify the branch as a single child to rightSide and delete its lastChild but that won’t work either. Thanks for your help!

```
var this_clone = leftSide.cloneNode(true);
rightSide.appendChild(this_clone);
rightSide.childNode[0].removeChild(rightSide.childNode[0].lastChild);
```

Comment: Please be more specific about "doesn't work" -- what did you get? Any error appear in console? It would be better if you can provide a fiddle with minimum code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner. So I make stupid errors. Your comment truly helped me. Now 'it' works :). It should have been childNodes, with an 's' at the end.